# What does vertical bar mean in X(k|k-1)?

Tags: notation, kalman-filter

I understand that "|" can mean many things.

Here, only 2 appear relevant: "Such that" or "Divided by" however for the equation I am trying to understand neither seems right.

What does it mean?

$\chi_i(k | k - 1) = f(\chi^a_i (k | k - 1), u(k - 1), t_{k - 1}).$

Comment: Where does this formula come from?

Comment: Unscented Kalman FIlter

Comment: See [Kalman Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Details).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you. I see an explanation of that page.

Comment: I think it denotes prediction in step k, based on the measurments of step (k-1).

Comment: $\chi_i(k | k - 1) = f(\chi^a_i (k | k - 1), u(k - 1), t_{k - 1}).$